# Having a resizable image map along with three.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, imagemap

I have an image map made in HTML and a three.js object. I'm very new to both but I would like to get the image map to resize as the window resizes(which it does already).

I know there are threads that somewhat cover this .however I seem to be running into trouble with where I should insert the JavaScript code since there is already stuff written for the three.js.

I have found this bit of JavaScript that appears to be a solution for others but I don't know where to put it.

```html
function mapRebuild(scaleValue) {
    var map = $("map"); // select your map or for all map you can choose $("map").each(function() { map = $(this);.....})
    map.find("area").each(function() { // select all areas
        var coords = $(this).attr("coords"); // extract coords
            coords = coords.split(","); // split to array
        var scaledCoords = "";
        for (var coord in coords) { // rebuild all coords with scaleValue
              scaledCoords += Math.floor(coords[coord] * scaleValue) + ",";
            }
        scaledCoords = scaledCoords.slice(0, -1); // last coma delete
        $(this).attr("coords", scaledCoords); // set new coords
        });
    }
```

My website is [aurnab.info](http://aurnab.info) and it runs best on safari and Firefox.

the code looks like this. and ideally i'd like to insert the above script somewhere.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  
  <title>aurnab saleh</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
  
   body {
    background:url("obj/me/homefinal.jpg");
    background-size:100%;
    margin: 0;
    width:1280px;
    height:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:fixed;
    
    }
   
   canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    }
  
   
  
   
   
   
  </style>
 </head>
 

 <body>

  
  <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>

  <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
  <img src="obj/me/homefinal.jpg" width="1280" height="800" usemap="#Map" border="0" style="opacity:0"/>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="650,365,713,422" href="http://soundcloud.com/bilderberg-group" target="_blank" alt="soundcloud" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="650,465,711,522" href="http://djgunk.tumblr.com" target="_blank" alt="tumblr" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="648,565,710,619" href="http://vimeo.com/aurnab" target="_blank" alt="vimeo" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="647,665,711,723" href="email.html" target="_blank" alt="gmail" />
</map>

   
  <script>

   var container, stats;

   var camera, scene, renderer;

   var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

   var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
   var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


   init();
   animate();


   function init() {
    
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    
    

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    
    //*zoom in or out: #up = out, #down = in
    camera.position.z = 250;
    
    // scene

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x000000 );
    
    scene.add( ambient );
    
     var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xff0000, 10, 0);
    light.position.set( 10, 100, 10 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xff0000, 10, 0);
    light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
    scene.add( light );
   
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xff0000, 10, 0);
    light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
    scene.add( light );
     var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
    directionalLight.position.set( 0, -5, 2 ).normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
    directionalLight.position.set( -10, -1, -1 ).normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );
    
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
    directionalLight.position.set( 10, 3, 3 ).normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );
    
    

    // model

    THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load( 'obj/me/malehead.obj', 'obj/me/malehead.mtl', function ( object ) {

     //*move entire object up or down on y axis****
     object.position.y =  60;
     object.rotation.y =  12.7;
     object.rotation.x =  .3;
     
     scene.add( object );

    } );

    //

    
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

  
   }
   

   function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 3;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 3;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    //* look left or right
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 10;
    //* look up his nostrils or not
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / -2;

   }

   //

   function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();

   }

   function render() {

    camera.position.x += (- mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .08;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .008;

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i getting this clear. If you want the image to resize as the window resizes then you can do something like this:

```
//apply an id to the image to use it in the javascript
<img id = "yourImageID" src="obj/me/homefinal.jpg" usemap="#Map"  style="opacity:0;width:1280;height:800;border:0;"/>

//set an id to all the areas (i do it in only one for example)
<area id = "area1" shape="rect" coords="650,365,713,422" href="http://soundcloud.com/bilderberg-group" target="_blank" alt="soundcloud" />

//in the script define a variable for the image tag and the area tag.
var image = document.getElementById("yourImageID");
var area1 = document.getElementByID("area1");
var coordsarea1=[];//table to store the map coordinates
coordsArea1.push(650); 
coordsArea1.push(365);
coordsArea1.push(713);
coordsArea1.push(422);

var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;//store the window Width to calculate the percentage after
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

now in the window resize function

```
function onWindowResize() {

  var percentX = windowWidth / window.innerWidth;//calculate the percentage of width change
  var percentY = windowHeight / window.innerHeight;//same for height change
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;//redefine the value of the width
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;//same for height

  image.style.width = window.innerWidth * percentX;//change the image width based on the window.innerWidth percentage change
  image.style.height = window.innerHeight * percentY;

  coordsArea1[0]*=percentX;//change the coords based on the percentage that the window  has changed
  coordsArea1[1]*=percentY;
  coordsArea1[2]*=percentX;
  coordsArea1[3]*=percentY;
  area1.coords = coordsArea1[0] + "," + coordsArea1[1] + "," + coordsArea1[2] + "," + coordsArea1[3];//not sure if is correct way to assign the values to the coords attribute

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 3; // shouldn't this be window.innerWidth/2?
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 3; //same as above?

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }
```

You should note that changing the width and the height manually will distort your image. Instead you can do width = 1280 and height = auto with a bit of change of the code.

Comment: The image already resizes to the window and it does distort the image which is fine. But I would like the image map to resize as well.

Comment: I have a code in the one I posted that changes the image map coordinates. I didn't try the code..i can try this tomorrow as I am on vacation. You should try my code though I think it will help

Comment: Im very new to javascript. how would i add multiple areas of the image map? and should i get rid of the html map i have and just do it all in js?

Comment: You can use document.createElement("map") and then document.createElement("area") to create the elements at the javascript side.I  will create an example and update my question.